# How to use JwtBearer to authenticate SignalR client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have project to use SignalR from desktop application. So my application have 2 method authentication. the one is cookie for web, the one is jwt for signalr client. cause the client comes from desktop.

How to exactly authentication, i check header request, client sent
`Authorization: Bearer testing`

in server, i assigns the token to `MessageReceivedContext.Token`. so i think, it automatically handle by some magic in background by `AuthorizeAttribute`. the description of property Bearer Token. `This will give the application an opportunity to retrieve a token from an alternative location.`

Client.js

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl("/socket", { 
                                accessTokenFactory: () => "testing"
                            })
                            .build();

connection.start();
```

Hub.cs

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class SocketHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() 
            => Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId));
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/socket";

    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Headers.Authorization;

            // If the request is for our hub...
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                // Read the token out of the query string
                
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to use JwtBearer to authenticate SignalR client?

As you may know, in standard web APIs, bearer tokens usually sent in an HTTP header. However, [SignalR is unable to set these headers in browsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0) when using some transports instead it send token using a query string parameter.

Therefore, you have to extract access token from querystring as following:

```
 var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
```

How to deal security issue:

Regarding the security concerns numerous measures, you could consider. For instance, you could [restrict Cross-origin resource sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing). In addition to this, your [ConnectionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-7.0#connectionid) should be keep secret.

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticate-users-connecting-to-a-signalr-hub) and [Security considerations in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-7.0).